# Angular DataTables serverSide update options and do new request

Tags: angularjs, server-side, angular-datatables

I am using angular-datatables very successfully in many cases. But now I got a special one: the data comes serverside and i have an external filter-field. The filter shall filter over different columns (serverside). I thought I can modify aoData in the option 'withFnServerData'. But the new request is never called. I tried with reloadData and rerender, but reloadData does not ask the server and rerender does the old request again, not the modified one.

```
$scope.surNameChanged = function() {
    var table = $('#test').DataTable();
    var predefinedFiltersNew = {0: {name: 'surName', value: $scope.surName}};
    vm.dtOptions = DataTableService.generalOptions('namesFiltered', null, 0, 'asc', false, predefinedFiltersNew);
//  vm.dtInstance.reloadData();
//  vm.dtInstance.rerender();
};
```

DataTableService.generalOptions:

```
r.generalOptions = function(address, filterColumns, defaultOrderColumn = 0, defaultOrderColumnDir = 'asc', footerCallback = false, predefinedFilters = null, search = false){
    var dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
    .withFnServerData(
        function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback, oSettings) {
            /**
                Filter
            **/
            for(var filt in predefinedFilters){
                var x = 0;
                for(var col in aoData[1].value){
                    if(aoData[1].value[col].data == predefinedFilters[filt].name){
                        aoData[1].value[col].search.value = predefinedFilters[filt].value;
                    }
                    x++;
                }
            }
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: url + address,
                data: {
                    start: aoData[3].value,
                    length: aoData[4].value,
                    draw: aoData[0].value,
                    order: aoData[2].value,
                    search: aoData[5].value,
                    columns: aoData[1].value
                },                    
                headers: {
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                var records = {
                    'draw': result.data.draw,
                    'recordsTotal': result.data.recordsTotal,
                    'recordsFiltered': result.data.recordsFiltered,
                    'data': result.data.data
                };
                if(result.data.totalTime != null){
                    r.totalTime = result.data.totalTime;
                }
                if(result.data.totalTimeFiltered != null){
                    r.totalTimeFiltered = result.data.totalTimeFiltered;
                }
                fnCallback(records);
            });
            }
    )
    .withDataProp('data')
    .withOption('processing', true)
    .withOption('serverSide', true)
    .withOption('bAutoWidth', true)
    .withOption('sLengthSelect', "ui selection dropdown")
    .withOption('order', [defaultOrderColumn, defaultOrderColumnDir])
    .withPaginationType('full_numbers');
    if(filterColumns != null){
        dtOptions.lightColumnFilterOptions = filterColumns;
        dtOptions.hasLightColumnFilter = true;
    }
    if(search == true){
        dtOptions.sDom = 'lrftip';
    }
    else{
        dtOptions.sDom = 'lrtip';
    }
    return dtOptions;
};
```

Comment: Have you used changeData() function??

Comment: Yes, i tried e.g. `vm.dtInstance.changeData({
            url: 'newRequest',
            dataSrc: 'payload.list'
        });` But nothing happened.